# Why is the base currect incorrect?

Tags: transistors, npn

[image]

My multimeter shows:
Ib=218uA why?

But my calculation shows, it should be: 8.5uA

I used the formula:
Ib=(3.1-0.7)/(10k+271k) [I take Beta=270, BC548 transistor.]

What is the problem? Why is Ib = 218uA, instead of 8.5uA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base resistor multiplication effect that you used in your calculation happens because the base emitter (R4 in your circuit) increases voltage both due to the base current and due to the collector current. So in order for the this effect to be what you expect, the transistor has to be in forward active mode. But here, the transistor is in saturation.

Consider if the transistor were forward-active and the base current were 8 uA. Then the collector current would be 2.3 mA. Then if there were 2.3 mA through R5, the collector voltage would have to be -227 V. Since the transistor isn't a power source, this can't happen, and we know the transistor is saturated.

Comment: then how do I calculate the base current, when the transistor is in saturation (I want the transistor to act like a switch.).

Comment: Easy way: You've already entered the circuit into CircuitLab, so just run the simulation. Hand calculation way: assume Vbe = 0.7 V and Vce = 0.2 V, and solve the simultaneous equations for the base and collector currents.

Answer (score 3):

The transistor is being saturated because R5 is way too high to allow the collector current Q1 needs to stay in the linear region.  Short accross R5 (make is 0), and the base current will be a lot lower.

Another way to look at this is that due to R5 being so high, most of the current thru R4 comes thru the base instead of thru the collector.